# Venting 2 traps

Tags: plumbing

[image]

So i need to move the vent line under the p-trap and above the sink p-trap

[image]

Can I run 2 traps off of one vent like this?

Comment: Robert, welcome. Please [take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you know what's expected of you. "Thank you" comments are discouraged.

Comment: Double check with your inspector on sizing. Mine required an up size on the washing machine's drain and vent.

Answer (score 4):

No you need to run it like this. [image] The vent is supposed to balance the pressure on the sewer side of the trap. Don't connect upstream of the trap as in your illustration, you will get sewer gas inside the house.

Comment: Also I don't think you need to use 2" for the vent. I think 1-1/2" is sufficient. (check your local code)